# How to host a website using FTP transfer?

Tags: web, hosting, web-hosting

When I buy a domain do I just upload all my files to the FTP server. Or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score -1):

You need to buy a hosting.

After that, send the domain to the hosting, you can find out the DNS on the hosting.

Then through FTP upload the files to the site directory on the hosting.